# HTTPDebuggerPro doesn't save response contents

Tags: windows-7, sniffing

I'm using HTTPDebuggerPro on Win 7 x64 and the problem is, it doesn't save response contents for some of the response bodies. Is there a way to fix it?

I've tried Charles... it's so lame, you need to configure an app to use it's localhost proxy and it can't preview received html, so no this app isn't worth using imho. By the way maybe one can recommend me another http monitor having html preview tool and working correctly under this OS?

Comment: I don't know about that tool, but Charles does the job for me when I need to save such content.  See http://www.charlesproxy.com/

Comment: It may have nothing to do with it, but I've found that W7 stores things in strange places when running some software.

Comment: So if you know the name of the file, do a search for it in \Users\ and see if it's hiding somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) is free, and can fully save any HTTP/HTTPS traffic.

If you want to preview the rendered HTML, use the "WebView" addon.